# How do I make HTTrack download at 15MBps?

Tags: download, website

I want to download some static websites. I have begun the process, but it seems that the maximum speed I can set to the GUI is a shade shorter than 1Mbps.

My down-link is steady until 54 Mbps, so I was wondering - how do I make HTTrack download, say, at 15MBps?

Answer (score 30):

You need to put 0 for max transfer rate and add --disable-security-limits in the scan rules box + 2nd screen that William Hilsum posted.

Comment: It works but what a pain...

Comment: I did those two things. Still i can't download faster than 400kB/s even though my connection is capable to reach 15MB/s.

Comment: Maybe have a look at the manual - for instance see flow section : --sockets=8  http://www.httrack.com/html/httrack.man.html

Answer (score 10):

Unless you are downloading from an office with a hefty internet connection or you have a good fibre connection, it is unlikely (but not impossible) you are connected to the internet at 54MBs, this is infact the speed that your computer is connected to the wireless router.

1Mbps may be the limit of your connection, other than that, I use HTTrack and whilst it is very good, it is slow as it has to index the site and build up a list of files to download.

If you want to check for limits, before you start the download, click on `Set options...` and you should be able to set any limit you want under the `Limits` or  `Flow Control` tabs.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yep - it's at the office. I did the test through speedtest.net. About the issue - note that you cannot enter more than 99999B/s ( or 100KB/s ) in max transfer rate ( your first shot ). Is there a way to increase that?

Comment: @PoorLuzer not that I am aware of - I usually just put 0 in the box to allow it to go at max.

Comment: Hmm .. I tried keeping it blank, but then it seemed to use the last setting. Will try setting to 0 and run it again.

Comment: I used this and Allan post below - from 25kbp now at 400kbps per file. Much difference. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't work for me. When I set it to 0, it automatically rate limits it back down.  I see the following message in the logs: `security warning: maximum bandwidth limited to 250000 to avoid server overload`

Answer (score 5):

I set the follow and am spiking at 17MiB/s on a 100Mb/s connection.

Limits:

- Max transfer rate (B/s)  = 0 B/s
- Max connections / second = Blank

Flow Control:

- Number of connections = 99
- Persistent connection (Keep-Alive) = Check (enabled)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using the command line, I get excellent speed with these parameters:

```
httrack "https://www.example.xyz/" -O "./example.xyz" "+*.example.xyz/*" --sockets=99 −−max−rate=0 --disable-security-limits −−keep−alive -v
```

Answer (score 1):

first,
to initiate speed optimization of HTTRACK first start the website download process. Check your existing speed !!

As most of you will notice the default transfer rate is bad slow or plain pathetic.

So now let's rev it up 8 - 10 x  No ambiguity no bad claims no hidden misleading confusions...

Now that your website is being downloaded, Go to **modify options** on top and click the **LIMITS** tab underneath.
come down to **MAX TRANSFER RATE** (BS) option.
CHANGE the default numeric value from 25000 to 90000
Click okay and exit.
go see the speed

Enjoy!